# I want to scrape a website whose pages do not change but the data in the pages on every table changes per page

Tags: json, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, python-requests

website: nafdac.gov.ng/our-services/registered-products

The code below runs but takes 7 hours to render 200 pages out of 5802, I'd appreciate it
if anybody can help me find how to scape this website faster

```
# pip install webdriver-manager --user
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, 
StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
import pandas as pd
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get('https://www.nafdac.gov.ng/our-services/registered- 
 products/')

container2 = []

wait_time_out = 20

ignored_exceptions 
=NoSuchElementException,StaleElementReferenceException,)


for _ in range(0, 5802+1):
    rows = WebDriverWait(driver, wait_time_out, 
ignored_exceptions=ignored_exceptions).until(
    ec.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//* 
[@id="table_1"]/tbody/tr')))

        for row in rows:
            time.sleep(10)
    container2.append([table_data.text for table_data in 
    row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'td')])
    WebDriverWait(driver, wait_time_out, 
    ignored_exceptions=ignored_exceptions).until(
    ec.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//* 
       [@id="table_1_next"]'))).click()
        time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: Calling `time.sleep(10)` so often might be the culprit - what happens if you remove it?

Answer (score 0):

it's a `.gov` site so there should be an api somewhere that would help make things faster, but when i try to get all data in one go they say

> There has been a critical error on this website.

but this should go faster than a week or so

```
import requests

ua={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_5_0) AppleWebKit/536.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.849.0 Safari/536.1'}
get_url="https://www.nafdac.gov.ng/our-services/registered-products/"
post_url="https://www.nafdac.gov.ng/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=get_wdtable&table_id=1"

payload={"wdtNonce":"73eab5a3d7","length":"10"}
with requests.session() as s:
    s.headers.update(ua)
    r=s.get(get_url)
    s.headers['Referer']=get_url
    for i in range(1,5802):
        payload['draw']=str(i)
        payload['start']=str((i-1)*10)
        r=s.post(post_url, data=payload)
        print(r.json())
```